# AngularJS' Regular tabs, about ng-transclude

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I have some questions.

I want to make a simple tab navigation that will use the angular `ng-view` 
much like the example on the AngularJS homepage [here](https://angularjs.org/). (in the **Create Components** section).

I want to have regular tabs, but when clicked, the ng-view to kick in and manage the template insertions.

---

Here's some code:

**`index.html`:**

```
...
<tabs class="list-group">
    <pane ng-repeat="pane in panes" class="list-group-item" title="{{pane.title}}" target="{{pane.target}}">I am a pane</pane>
</tabs>
...
```

**`script.js:`**

```
angular.module('components', ['ngRoute'])

    .directive('tabs', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: '.tabbable',
            scope: {},
            controller: function($scope, $location, $element) {
                var panes = $scope.panes = [];

                /**
                 * TODO
                 */
                $scope.select = this.select = function(pane) {
                    angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
                        pane.selected = false;
                    });
                    pane.selected = true;
                }

                this.addPane = function(pane) {
                    panes.push(pane);
                }

                /* Set active pane */
                this.currentPane = $location.path().slice(1);
            },
            /* TODO: get rid of display: none; */
            template:
                '<div class="tabbable">' +
                    '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
                        '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">'+
                            '<a href="#{{pane.target}}" ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>' +
                        '</li>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                    '<div style="display: none;" ng-transclude></div>' +
                '</div>',
            replace: true
        };
    })

    .directive('pane', function() {
        return {
            require: '^tabs',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { title: '@', target: '@', active: '@active' },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
                if (scope.target == tabsCtrl.currentPane) {
                    tabsCtrl.select(scope);
                }
                tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
            },
            template:
                '<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}"></div>',
            replace: true
        };
    })
```

My main point of confusion is the `ng-transclude`. I don't understand why I need a transcluded div when I don't want the tab content at all. The code above works, except that I don't like the part where I need to hide  the div (with `display: none;`). I think that's not they right way to go and if someone can explain this stuff to me, I'd be really grateful.